# How to reinstall Windows Server VM on Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

My Windows Server VM on Azure crashed due to a ransom virus. How can I use Azure to reinstall the Windows Server so it is back to its original stage? I hope by this process it can keep the most of the setup in Azure, such as public IP, machine name, etc.

Comment: The easiest way is create a new VM with windows server. delete that VM and swap that disk with current disk in your current VM. Does it help?

Comment: Maybe you can try the redeploy of the VM on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Redeploy migrates your VM to a new host. You loose your temporary disk, but keep the system disk. So this will probably not work.

You can however run "Reapply", "This operation will rerun VM provisioning and help solve the VM failed state"

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that redeploy and reapply both can't work in this case.
So eventually I just create a new VM.